# Why can't I set global electron variables in my HTML for Typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron

Currently I am doing a personal project where I am using Electron and Typescript, at the moment both my Main.js and Renderer.js are Typescript files that are being compiled. So Main.ts and a webpack bundled React Typescript app. My current issue is that whenever I try to set the variable "remote" in my template (main.html) it is currently working inside the template, however I can't access the "remote" variable inside my Typescript app. I will demonstrate below:

```
// Template - main.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>League Desktop</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="mount"></div>
    <script src="../node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.remote = require('electron').remote;
       console.log(remote); // Returns object and works inside this script tag
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/static/main.bundle.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

however as I mentioned, even though an object is returned and works within the script tag; it does not work in my app. Which is funny because I remember doing a project a while ago and this worked flawlessly. My current workaround involved importing the "remote" module into my actual file/class before I can use it while using two different webpack configs, one of them for the React app which has "target: 'electron-renderer'" and one for the main electron app which has "target: 'electron-main'". Observe that this method doesnt work without the different configs and the correct targets. So this wont work:

```
// TitleBar.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";

export default class TitleBar extends Component<any, any> {
  public _close(){
    remote.getCurrentWindow().close(); // This does not work!
    // Without webpack targets and using global variables in template!
  }

  public render() {
    return <button onClick={this._close}>Close Window</button>;
   }    
}
```

note that without adding the "targets" to webpack, remote or any other electron module won't actually load. Assuming that the proper "targets" are set; this should work:

```
// TitleBar.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { remote } from "electron";

export default class TitleBar extends Component<any, any> {
  public _close(){
    remote.getCurrentWindow().close(); // This works now!
    // With proper webpack targets and no global variables in template!
  }

  public render() {
    return <button onClick={this._close}>Close Window</button>;
   }    
}
```

This is getting pretty long so I will end it quickly, but why does it not work the way I remember it used to? Is it Webpack or Typescript that hinders me? Can imagine it would be pretty annoying to add an import for "remote" everytime I need it, like React.

Anyways, thank you for your time and I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a reference of remote on global object in main file.
You can do that as follows:-

```
global.remote = remote; // import remote as it works for you prior to this statement.
```

Thereafter you can refer to this in other ts files as well without importing. But you will have to use, global.remote instead of directly using remote

Comment: I added this to my entryfile and it works as expected! Thank you!

Comment: If we don't import 'electron', how would typescript know about electron.remote while compiling our typescript file.